# is not a function on dojo.ready (dojo 1.7 related)

Tags: dom, dojo

I am developing using dojo 1.7 and am getting an error.. My aim is to move items from one multi select box to another. The page is long so I only copied the relevant parts.

Here's my head js code and the problem comes after dojo.ready. The variable "newStore" works great so I know that is executing fine. it's the dojo.query("button.switch") that seems to be the issue. The firebug error I get is

```
dojo.query("button.switch").connect is not a function
```

and this error is thrown on page load. The code is....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["dijit/dijit"]);
require(["dojo/parser"]);
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer"]);
require(["dijit/layout/ContentPane"]);
require(["dijit/layout/AccordionContainer"]);
require(["dijit/layout/TabContainer"]);
require(["dijit/form/CheckBox"]);
require(["dijit/form/Button"]);
require(["dijit/form/ComboBox"]);
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox"]);
require(["dijit/form/SimpleTextarea"]);
require(["dijit/form/TextBox"]);
require(["dijit/form/Textarea"]);
require(["dijit/form/MultiSelect"]);
require(["clipart/ArrowLeft"]);
require(["clipart/ArrowRight"]);
require(["dijit/form/FilteringSelect"]);
require(["dijit/form/RadioButton"]);
require(["dijit/form/Select"]);
require(["dojox/layout/GridContainer"]);
require(["dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore"]);
require(["dijit/Tree"]);
require(["dojo/ready"]);


dojo.ready(function(){
var newStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    url: "http://0:3000/sample/sample_name"
   });
   dijit.byId('sc_sample_name').set('store',newStore);

dojo.query("button.switch")
  .connect("onclick",function(e){
    switch(e.target.id.toString()){
      case "left" : dijit.byId("at2").addSelected(dijit.byId("at1")); break;
      case "right" : dijit.byId("at1").addSelected(dijit.byId("at2")); break;
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

This is a page load issue which is why I am not including the HTML (which is huge). Has anyone seen this behavior before? Janie

Comment: Can you show the lines where *button.switch* is declared. This query will give you nodelist of button with class switch.

Comment: Also can you check what is returned from dojo.query("button.switch")? Are you able to access first element of the nodelist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are loading [baseless dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/hello_dojo/), i.e. your `dojoConfig`/`data-dojo-config` has an option `async:true`, which switches Dojo to *baseless* mode since version 1.7.

Use `query("button.switch").on("click", function(e) { ...})` instead of `connect`:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/query"
], function(
    ready,
    query
) {

    ready(function() {

        query("button.switch").on("click", function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.id);            
        }); 
    });  
});​
```

or do not switch into *baseless* mode.

Try it yourself at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/LMdBd/, change `async: true` to `async: false` or delete it completely and `connect` will work:

[image]

Comment: This is PERFECT! This solves so many issues and not only did you give me a great answer, but you also shed some light on the process. I very much appreciate that. Answer karma for you! Janie